# web3js + nodejs: calls to methods.deposit() creates a transaction that is pending forever

Tags: web3js, transactions, nodejs, polygon

I'm trying to make simple calls to a contract in order to harvest the acccumulated yield.
To to that I'm performing this call:

```
const h = await polycatFarm.methods.deposit(25, 0, walletAddress).send({
                from: walletAddress,
                gas: 20000000,
                gasPrice: 20000000,
                nonce: nonce
            })
                .on('confirmation', (confirmationNumber, receipt) => {
                    console.log('=> confirmation: ' + confirmationNumber);
                })
                .on('transactionHash', hash => {
                    console.log('=> hash');
                    console.log(hash);
                    //console.log("HASH: ", hash);
                    transHash = hash;
                })
                .on('receipt', receipt => {
                    console.log('=> reciept');
                    console.log(receipt);
                })
                .on('error', console.error)
```

The transaction is submitted to the blockchain (Matic mainnet), however it stays in "pending" state forever.

[image]

After one minute, the above call exits with error state staying that 50 blocks have passed but the transaction looks still pending...

this is the server I'm attached to: wss://rpc-mainnet.matic.quiknode.pro

Do you have some clue why this behavior?

Thanks a lot for your support!
Marco

Comment: What did you use as nonce?

Comment: i've tried this: 

`const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(walletAddress);`

however either I use it or not, the problem persists. I'm wondering if it is some sort of very low SLAs on the server I'm using...

Comment: I don't know much about Matic network but if it works like Ethereum causes of pending transactions are not enough balance to cover value and tx fees, low tx fees, incorrect nonce. Also if you have a pending transaction then following transaction will be pending until the first is mined.